# NancyFx (1.4.3): this.Binding<> fails with ModelBindingException (inner exception: MissingMethodException)

Tags: nancy

I received the  *ModelBindingException (inner exception: MissingMethodException)* when using **this.Bind<>()**, and I found the answer to do with mixing old and new DLLs (via NuGet).  Full answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be mis-aligned (mixing old and new versions) nuget package versions between projects. I corrected all packages for running with Nancy 1.4.3 as follows, as my current configuration:

(see packages.config - this list is not complete)

```
Nancy 1.4.3
Nancy.Elmah 0.1.8
Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet 1.4.1
Nancy.RouteHelpers 1.0.6
Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet 1.4.1
Nancy.Viewengines.Razor 1.4.3
```

Also, I used the Manage NuGet Packages For Solution to ensure the right version was hooked up to each project.